# sorting array of objects swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of object, each object contains a discount rate , I need to sort them increasingly by their rate,

```
struct ShopDetails {
    var shopId: Int?
    var discountRate: String?
    init(with json: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
        shopId = json["id"] as? Int
        discountRate = json["discount"] as? String

    }
```

I tired to sort them using this method;

```
 func getShopsByDiscount() {
        let sortedImages = self.copyOfShops.sorted(by: { (shop1: ShopDetails, shop2: ShopDetails) -> Bool in
            return Int(shop1.discountRate) < Int(shop2.discountRate)
        })

    }
```

I tried to cast the rate to integer, since its been received form the backend as string, but I got an error: 
`value of type Any has no member discountRate.`
any idea how to do it? if there is a way to do it without casting it will be better

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere? The error message has a lowercase `discountrate` where your code has `discountRate`.

Comment: edited please check

Comment: What is `copyOfShops`? It's supposed to be `[ShopDetails]` – which avoids the error by the way  –  but I guess it's `NSArray`

Comment: its the array which contains the objects which I want to sort, its an array of shops

Comment: Is it of type `[ShopDetails]` or something else?

Comment: My question was unclear. What is the exact **type** of the array?

Comment: yes it is an Array of type  [ShopDetails]

Comment: And why is `discountRate` an (optional) *string?* Make it a Double and save the trouble!

Comment: Long story short: If it's `NSArray` it has no type information and the error occurs. If it's Swift `[ShopDetails]` the error must not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to verify that the array you're starting with is of type `[ShopDetails]`. The error indicates that this is probably an Objective-C `NSArray`, which won't work as well in Swift. If you're unclear about this, I suggest you Google the topic: there's no reason to use `NSArray` in Swift.

Below, I assume the array is the correct type (`[ShopDetails]`). From here, you need to do two additional things, because `discountRate` is of type `String?`.

1. You need to check if the string is actually there
2. You need to check if it can actually be expressed as an `Int`.

With these things in mind, your sort function can look like this:

```
let sortedImages = copyOfShops.sorted(by: {
    (shop1: ShopDetails, shop2: ShopDetails) -> Bool in
    if let shop1String = shop1.discountRate, let shop1Value = Int(shop1String),
        let shop2String = shop2.discountRate, let shop2Value = Int(shop2String) {
        return shop1Value < shop2Value
    }
    return true
})
```

That being said, the **best** way to handle this is to change the type of `discountRate` from `String?` to `Int`, and do the above checks when you `init(with json: Dictionary<String,Any>)`. If the server giving you the dictionary is something you control, have it switch to passing back Ints instead of Strings, and stop dealing with optionals if you don't have to.